# Debian distribution with Openbox already installed

Tags: debian, openbox, debian-installer

I am looking for a Debian iso that has already Openbox installed and configured. I know there are some Debian based distributions with Openbox installed ([Archbang](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for instance) but I am looking for a pure Debian experience with Openbox.

I plan to use Openbox alone (ie: not combined with Gnome or KDE for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian LXDE installation image configures Openbox by default (since that's the default LXDE window manager). It's available at http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.2.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.2.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso for `amd64` for example; you can look at the various possibilites starting from https://www.debian.org/CD/.

Comment: Thanks. And then I would have to disable the LXDE desktop environment to have a "pure" Openbox experience like in Crunchbang or Archbang?

Comment: I guess so, yes (I'm not familiar with Crunchbang or Archbang).

Comment: Ok then I will ask another question to swith from Openbox + LXDE to Openbox only.

Answer (score 0):

If I clear understand what you wants: Try [crunchbang++](https://crunchbangplusplus.org/) or [Calculate Linux Scratch (CLS)](http://www.calculate-linux.ru/main/en/cls)